# using metaclass for default attribute init

Tags: python, init, metaclass

Let's say I have a resource class that looks as such:

```py
class Resource(metaclass=ResourceInit):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

My goal is to create a metaclass, i.e. `ResourceInit`, that handles automatically assigning attributes to the instantiated `Resource`.

The following code I have, that does not work:

```py
config = {"resources": {"some_resource": {"a": "testA", "b": "testB"}}}

class ResourceInit(type):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        obj = super(ResourceInit, self)

        argspec = inspect.getargspec(obj.__self__.__init__)

        defaults = {}

        for argument in [x for x in argspec.args if x != "self"]:
            for settings in config["resources"].values():
                for key, val in settings.items():
                    if key == argument:
                        defaults.update({argument: val})
            if os.environ.get(argument):
                defaults.update({argument: os.environ[argument]})

        defaults.update(kwargs)
        for key, val in defaults.items():
            setattr(obj, key, val)
        return obj
```

The idea is, using this metaclass, upon instantiating

```
res = Resource()
```

will automatically populate `a` and `b` if it exists in the `config` or as an environment variable..

Obviously this is a dummied example, where `a` and `b` will be substantially more specific, i.e. `xx__resource__name`.

My questions:

1. Can you pass an argument to the metaclass within the subclass, i.e. `resource="some_resource"`
2. How can I get this to work as any normal class if either `config` or `os.environ` is not set, i.e. `x = Test()` results in `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'`

Comment: A class method would be far simpler than a metaclass.

Comment: What's wrong with assigning the values derived from `config` or an environment variable to `a` and `b` directly inside the `__init__` method of `Resource` itself?

Comment: @blhsing. I was thinking the same thing. Everything about this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: What is `Test` in the last part, `x = Test()`?

Comment: This is overly complicated because there are resources that exist with extremely large configs, and i would rather rely on someone instantiating without the need for configs unless they do not exist.. @MadPhysicist i meant `x = Resource()`

Comment: @chepner - a class method would be a solid idea, but i need to save backwards compatibility that already relies on `x = Resource()` instead of `x = Resource.from_config()`

Comment: @sgerbhctim. Let me know if there is anything I missed in my answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist will get back to you shortly.. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative**

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. The simple solution looks like this:

```
def get_configured(name, value, config):
    if value is None:
        try:
            value = next(c for c in config['resources'].values() if name in c)[name]
        except StopIteration:
            value = os.environ.get(name, None)
    return value

class Resource:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = get_configured('a', a, config)
        self.b = get_configured('a', b, config)
```

The function is reusable, and you can easily modify it to minimize the amount of boilerplate each class will have.

**Full Answer**

However, if you do insist on taking the metaclass road, you can simplify that as well. You can add as many keyword-only arguments as you want to your class definition (**Question 1**).

```
class Resource(metaclass=ResourceInit, config=config): ...
```

`config`, and any other arguments besides `metaclass` will get passed directly to the `__call__` method of the meta-metaclass. From there, they get passed to `__new__` and `__init__` in the metaclass. You must therefore implement `__new__`. You might be tempted to implement `__init__` instead, but `object.__init_subclass__`, which is called from `type.__new__`, raises an error if you pass in keyword arguments:

```
class ResourceInit(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, *, config, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
```

Notice that last arguments, `config` and `kwargs`. Positional arguments are passed as `bases`. `kwargs` must not contain unexpected arguments before it is passed to `type.__new__`, but should pass through anything that `__init_subclass__` on your class expects.

There is no need to use `__self__` when you have direct access to `namespace`. Keep in mind that this will only update the default if your `__init__` method is actually defined. You likely don't want to mess with the parent `__init__`. To be safe, let's raise an error if `__init__` is not present:

```
        if '__init__' not in namespace or not callable(getattr(cls, '__init__')):
            raise ValueError(f'Class {name} must specify its own __init__ function')
        init = getattr(cls, '__init__')
```

Now we can build up the default values using a function similar to what I showed above. You have to be careful to avoid setting defaults in the wrong order. So while all keyword-only arguments can have optional defaults, only the positional arguments at the end of the list get them. That means that the loop over positional defaults should start from the end, and should stop immediately as soon as a name with no defaults is found:

```
def lookup(name, configuration):
    try:
        return next(c for c in configuration['resources'].values() if name in c)[name]
    except StopIteration:
        return os.environ.get(name)

...

        spec = inspect.getfullargspec(init)

        defaults = []
        for name in spec.args[:0:-1]:
            value = lookup(name, config)
            if value is None:
                break
            defaults.append(value)

        kwdefaults = {}
        for name in spec.kwonlyargs:
            value = lookup(name, config)
            if value is not None:
                kwdefaults[name] = value
```

The expression `spec.args[:0:-1]` iterates backwards through all the positional arguments except the first one. Remember that `self` is a conventional, not mandatory name. Removing it by index is therefore much more robust than removing it by name.

The key to making the `defaults` and `kwdefaults` values mean anything is to assign them to the `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` on the actual `__init__` function object (**Question 2**):

```
        init.__defaults__ = tuple(defaults[::-1])
        init.__kwdefaults__ = kwdefaults
        return cls
```

`__defaults__` must be reversed and converted to a tuple. The former is necessary to get the order of the arguments right. The latter is required by the `__defaults__` descriptor.

**Quick Test**

```
>>> configR = {"resources": {"some_resource": {"a": "testA", "b": "testB"}}}
>>> class Resource(metaclass=ResourceInit, config=configR):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
... 
>>> r = Resource()
>>> r.a
'testA'
>>> r.b
'testB'
```

**TL;DR**

```
def lookup(name, configuration):
    try:
        return next(c for c in configuration['resources'].values() if name in c)[name]
    except StopIteration:
        return os.environ.get(name)

class ResourceInit(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        config = kwargs.pop('config')
        cls = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

        if '__init__' not in namespace or not callable(getattr(cls, '__init__')):
            raise ValueError(f'Class {name} must specify its own __init__ function')
        init = getattr(cls, '__init__')
        spec = inspect.getfullargspec(init)

        defaults = []
        for name in spec.args[:0:-1]:
            value = lookup(name, config)
            if value is None:
                break
            defaults.append(value)

        kwdefaults = {}
        for name in spec.kwonlyargs:
            value = lookup(name, config)
            if value is not None:
                kwdefaults[name] = value

        init.__defaults__ = tuple(defaults[::-1])
        init.__kwdefaults__ = kwdefaults

        return cls
```

Comment: This is fantastic... my one question on how to extend something like this: lets say that we have a `class Resource` that takes in `a, b, c` arguments... the metaclass will be able to find `a, b` via the config, but not `c`.  Using this currently, if there exists that extra `c` argument, the error: `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'` appears, where I would like for it to only be missing `c`.  is that possible?

Comment: @sgerbhctim. Well that's the problem. You can't have an argument with no default value following arguments with default values. So you can have some default value assigned to `c` regardless of what is found, or rearrange the parameter list (which is very bad).